# How do I get all financial records related to a job using IPP v2

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

My company wants to integrate our app with Quickbooks using IPP v2 API. We would like to retrieve all financial records related to a job. I have been playing around with the API using the API explorer. I see that I have to retrieve the data separately using entities like Bill, Invoice, Journal, etc. However, I didn't seem to find a way to filter the data returned in those entities by job.

Currently, I have to query the entire Bill table for example and to look for JobId under ReimbursableInfo myself. It's not feasible since I have to do the same thing for other tables.

Am I missing something from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In docs, JobID is not mentioned as a filterable attribute.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/bill#Retrieving_Bills_Using_a_Query_Filter

You need to do client side filtering.

For Invoice, you can use JobIdSet attribute.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/invoice

Thanks